# Passing an int to a new ViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, int

Ive spent a month trying to pass my int to a new view. My int is called score and is connected to a label called scorelab. The user increases the score and once the they run out of time game switches views to game over screen and i would like the users score to be displayed on the game over screen in a label. The game play controller is called `GamePlayViewController` and the gave over controller is called `GameDidEndViewController`. I'm tired of trying to get this to work. I have looked at every tutorial possible but nothing seems to work for my case. Please help me i would appreciate it so so much, this is the very last part of game that I need to finish. Thank you in advance!

Sorry here is the code:

GamePlayViewController.h

```
#import "GameDidEndViewController.h"


int score;

IBOutlet UILabel *scorelab;
```

GamePlayViewController.m

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{

if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"GameOver"])
{

    GameDidEndViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];

    [vc setscore2: score];
}
}
```

GameDidEndViewController.h

```
#import "GamePlayViewController.h"
IBOutlet UILabel *scorelab2;
int score2;
}
@property (nonatomic , assign) int score2;
@property (nonatomic , assign) UILabel *scorelab2;
```

GameDidEndViewController.m

```
@synthesize score2 , scorelab2;
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
scorelab2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d", score2];
[super viewWillAppear: animated];  
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? If you have been trying for a month, surely it means you have some code that doesn't work.  We are are here to tell you why it doesn't work, not do it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some tutorial for passing data between `ViewControllers` using `Storyboard`:

1. [Storyboards Segue Tutorial: Pass Data Between View Controllers](http://www.appcoda.com/storyboards-ios-tutorial-pass-data-between-view-controller-with-segue/)
2. [Tutorial on How-To Pass Data Between Two View Controllers](http://klanguedoc.hubpages.com/hub/IOS-5-Tutorial-on-How-To-Pass-Data-Between-Two-View-Controllers)

or use something like this:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:...]) {
        MyViewController *controller = (MyViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        controller.score = score;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is becoming routine for people to add there objects and properties in their .m file.  So if you are getting an error where controller.score = score; make sure that in your destination view controller that you are claiming your integer in your .h file and not in your .m file.  Then your error will disappear.

Answer (score 4):

What you do is create a property in `GameDidEndViewController` to hold the passed in `score` value.

```
@interface GameDidEndViewController : UIViewController {

....
}
@property(nonatomic,assign) int score;
@end
```

Make sure you `@synthesize score` in the `@implementation`(.m).

Now when you init and show the `GameDidEndViewController` you set the score, likely something like this.

```
GameDidEndViewController *end = .....// init the view.
end.score = score; // assuming you're doing this from GamePlayViewController where it has an int named `score`
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: I don't think this is for storyboards... should have mentioned i need it for storyboard